# How to retrieve omniture using omniture developer api

Tags: api, adobe-analytics

We have programmed in android to track omniture using page name using the code

```
Analytics.trackState(pageName, params);
```

The params contains lot if data like `s.channel`, `s.prop`, `Prop`, `s.eVar`

Now: We want get all the params which got recorded in omniture by hitting [this link](https://api.omniture.com/admin/1.4/rest/)

I am trying to use [the nomniture](https://github.com/imartingraham/nomniture) module to call Report, but it is very difficult to understand the parameters to choose a particular page

My Node.js Code

```
var Client = require('omniture').Client, c = new Client(username,
        sharedSecret, 'sanJose'), reportData = {
    "rsid_list" : [ reportSuiteId ]
}
```

How to use `s.pageName` in a request to retrieve the recorded variables for a particular custom page name

I tried to use `Report.QueueTrended`, `Report.QueueOvertime`, `Report.QueueRanked` followed by `Report.Get` but I am not getting anything

I always ended up getting `errorCode 5003`, `The report may contain imcomplete data. Please try again later`

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: I realize this is kind of old, but I wanted to comment anyway in case this is still a problem. Can you edit your post to include the report description that you're sending in your request? I'm not a node expert, but that would really help someone who is. Also, your API call appears to be hitting the old 1.3 API (Report.QueueRanked) and the San Jose data center is gone. Is there a newer library you can use?